# Fill a column with characters x times from a list of character in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, row, fill

I want to fill a dataframe with characters from a list x times, but when I try to use function `fill` it doesn't work. My dataset is quite big and I need to do everything in a loop, since I need to do it all over for the next iteration. This is my code thus far

```
sp <- c("Deer", "Moose", "Wildboar", "Bear", "Wolf")
mon <- 1:7

m <- matrix(nrow = 35, ncol = 2)
data <-  as.data.frame(m)
colnames(m) <- c("Species", "Month")
```

Now, I want to fill column "Month" with 1-7 5 times, so the column looks like this (11111222223333344444555556666677777). I want to fill the column "Species" with DeerDeerDeerDeerDeerMooseMooseMooseMooseMooseWildboarWildboarWildboarWildboarWildboarBearBearBearBearBearWolfWolfWolfWolfWolf.

I tried to do this in a loop but it only created four new columns and only filled the first four rows with deer, moose, wildboar and bear.

```
  for(i in 1:length(sp)) {
    for(j in 1:length(mon)) {
      data[i,j] <- sp[i]
    }
  }
```

Have anyone else experienced the same problem?

Comment: will this work? rep(1:7, each = 5)
rep(c('Deer','Moose','Wildboard','Bear'), each = 5)

Comment: Here is an idea: `rep(1:3, each = 3)`, read about "rep" and "paste". No need for forloops.

Comment: `data.frame(Species = rep(sp, each = 7),  Month = rep(mon, each = 5))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rep` with `each` command.

```
df <- data.frame(Species = rep(sp, each = 7),  Month = rep(mon, each = 5))
df

#    Species Month
#1      Deer     1
#2      Deer     1
#3      Deer     1
#4      Deer     1
#5      Deer     1
#6      Deer     2
#7      Deer     2
#8     Moose     2
#9     Moose     2
#10    Moose     2
#....
#....
```